# time invariance $ y (t) = x(\frac{t}{3})$

Tags: linear-systems

> check time variance of this system
> $$y (t) = x(\frac{t}{3})$$

my solution
$$y_1(t) = x_1(t/3)\\
y_2(t) = x_2(t)=  x_1(\dfrac{t}{3}-t_o)$$
where
$$ x_2(t) = x_1(t-t_o)\\
y_1(t - t_o) = x_1(\dfrac{t-t_o}{3}) \ne y_2(t)$$
is this correct?

Comment: Looks good. You applied the test of time invariance and got the right answer!